# In ESS/Emacs, how can I get the R process buffer to scroll to the bottom after a C-c C-j or C-c C-r

Tags: emacs, r, ess

In ESS when I am evaluating chunks of code in a .R file using C-c C-j or C-c C-r (to send the line or region to a running R process), how can I get the R buffer to scroll down automatically, such that after evaluating a region the cursor is at the bottom, at the prompt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably a bunch of ways to do it. In my .emacs.d I have

```
  (setq comint-prompt-read-only t)
  (setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input t)
  (setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)
  (setq comint-move-point-for-output t)
```

You might also be interested in [this code](http://www.kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2009/10/12/make-shift-enter-do-a-lot-in-ess/), originally from Felipe Csaszar, which lets you do what you ask and a few other nice things besides.

Comment: `(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)` is likely a bad idea.  I used to have this whole block of commands in .emacs (as copied from emacswiki), but `(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)` would sometimes break the interaction between the buffer and inferior ESS process, forcing me to kill R and start session over.

Comment: I too have found that read-only can lead to issues with ESS. Beware.

Comment: Yeah, I removed it myself ages ago as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [auto-scrolling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Scrolling.html#Auto-Scrolling) in emacs doc. For my part:

`customize-variable RET scroll-down-aggressively RET`

scroll-down-aggressively set to 1 did the job.

Comment: working for me with Python console, not tried with R one

Answer (score -1):

[DJJ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122548) works perfectly for ESS and polymode in Spacemacs.

First, put `(scroll-down-aggressively 1)` within the `defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` section of the configuration file, e.g. `~/.spacemacs`.

Then, evaluate the line using `SPC , e r` or restart configuration `SPC f e d`.

Emacs 27 complained about the above line because "Symbol's function definition is void" so I had to change it as follow to achieve the same result:

```
(setq scroll-down-aggressively 0.01)
```